# How to write Powershell help for my cmdlets

Tags: powershell-2.0

I've written my own Powershell cmdlets in c#. How can I add help test, so the I can get a more complete description when users use "Get-Help MYCMDLET"

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell cmdlet help is stored as an XML file. There is some information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/09/14/Draft-Creating-Cmdlet-Help.aspx). Then there is the [Cmdlet Help Editor Tool](https://pscmdlethelpeditor.codeplex.com/).

And more recently, the [Cmdlet and Help Designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/10/16/announcing-open-source-powershell-cmdlet-and-help-designer.aspx).

Comment: The former link is broken, while the latter is a source-only release that requires the user to compile the solution code stored on CodePlex. Are there any other options out there for authoring help for custom PowerShell cmdlets ?

Comment: @Alex: I changed the first tool link to the codeplex site; I think it's the same tool, but hard to tell.